# Не верно работает strip_tags

Tags: php

Из БД достаются данные (HTML файл) в переменную `$uItem['uBody_2']`. Начинаю использовать функцию strip_tags:

```
strip_tags( html_entity_decode($uItem['uBody_2'], ENT_QUOTES));
```

Ожидаю увидеть надпись "Привет, мир!".
Но вместо этого вижу содержание тега style:

```
body {width:100% !important;-web...
```

Привожу весь код из БД:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
     body {width:100% !important;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;margin-top...
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
             Привет, мир!
  </body>
```

т.е. `strip_tags` удаляет теги `style`, но почему-то оставляет данные между ними. Как решить эту проблему? Может быть, есть какая-нибудь функция, которая достает только текст?

Тестовый вариант [тут](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad401a6fea87152967644b3a080d6782e06bacf5).

Comment: А почему у вас стили в фигурных скобках? У вас там точно атрибут style? Если не сложно приведите точное содержимое $uItem['uBody_2'] в вопросе? strip_tags не должен оставлять атрибуты вырезаемых тэгов.

Comment: Да, точно: <style>
body {width:100% !important;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-right:0;margin-left:0;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;}

         
</style>

Comment: Посмотрите сами, все оставляет: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad401a6fea87152967644b3a080d6782e06bacf5

Comment: В <style>, да, все оставит, так как это содержимое тэга. Вы сами хотите эти стили сохранить? Или удалить?

Answer (score 1):

`strip_tags` удаляет всего навсего теги HTML, а чтобы удалить и содержимое тега можно использовать, например, регулярные выражения. В крайнем случае, если не хотите использовать регулярки, - подключите файл CSS и поместите стили туда.